# Node.JS и ожидание колбеков

Tags: node.js

Приветствую, коллеги.

Новичок в Node, но нужно реализовать кое-какой функционал. Застрял на одном моменте, и как я понял из интернетов - весьма важном.

Пример (клиент обращается к серверу по /someURL через AJAX):

```
// обработчик /someURL
exports.myfoo = function(req, res){
    SQL.query('select * from users', function(err, results) {
        if(results) {
            res.send("{'key' : 'value'}");
            res.end();
        }
    });
}
```

Как видно из кода, мне надо взять что-то из базы и, проверив данные, отправить JSON клиенту. Но есть проблема(мне кажется, вы уже догадались) - Node.JS не дожидается выполнения callback-функции и, ничего не отправив, завершает выполнение обработчика. На клиент приходит пустота.

Как решить эту задачу? Спасибо за внимание

Comment: Я вот нарыл пару библиотек для подобных случаев. Самый известный - async. я на верном пути или нет?

Comment: а добавьте ветку else  в вышеприведенный пример. и отошлите на клиент какое-нибудь сообщение. Если оно придет, значит проблема то в другом.

Comment: Ох я идиот. Действительно, надо было добавить else. А ответ не приходил потому, что условие тупо не выполнялось )) Простите за глупость. Спасибо, KoVadim )

Answer (score 1):

Функция составлена правильно, т.к. синтаксис такой:

```
query(sql, callback)
```

Вероятно возникает либо ошибка, либо еще что-то.

Проверяйте:

```
 SQL.query('select * from users', function(err,results){
     if(err){ 
         console.log("error");
         console.log(err);
         return;  
     }
     console.log( results );
     var r = results.fetchSync("all",true);
     console.log( r );
     SQL.disconnect();
 });
```

Comment: Я проверяю на ошибки, конечно. Просто я в коде указал проверку. Но даже с ней - ничего не меняется.